# How to call a reactor function from a coroutine context?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

The scenario is I'm developing a Kotlin microservice that uses coroutine and one of the libraries I'm using (reactor.Kafka) is expecting a flux publisher.
How can I bridge the two? (I'm using `kotlinx-coroutines-reactive` and `kotlinx-coroutines-reactor` to bridge the other way around when consuming an event I open `mono{}` block and call a suspending function but in this case its the other way around).

The function I'm trying to call:

```kotlin
kafkaSender.send(Flux.just(SenderRecord.create(record, "0")))
```

Comment: What exactly would you like to do? Convert the returned Flux into something else? Did you check the await... extensions methods?

Comment: @MartinTarjányi I'm trying to produce a new event, I tried the different await methods, but I think I need something to bridge the coroutine context I'm in (inside a suspend function) to call a function that receives a flux publisher. But maybe I'm all wrong.

Comment: I think you should be fine just by calling one of the await... methods after the send. They take care of the bridging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, we do not see bridging methods in [kotlinx-coroutines-reactor](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-reactor) to `await` from a `Flux`. But:

> Note that `Mono` and `Flux` are subclasses of Reactive Streams' `Publisher` and extensions for it are covered by the kotlinx-coroutines-reactive module.

---

I think you can simply call `.awaitLast()`.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-reactive/kotlinx.coroutines.reactive/await-last.html

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but calling await blocks the thread until we receive a response, isn't there a way to call the function without blocking the thread?

Comment: it doesn't block the thread, it just suspends the execution